# How to set nstimer in reverse order

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nstimer

I have 3 UIlabel

First  UILabel show- hh(hours)

Second UILabel show- mm(minutes)

Third  UILabel show- ss(seconds)

**Time is already showing in UILabels , but it has to run or tick reversely.**

Means- 10:04:45 will come to 00:00:00--

This is what i am trying.

```
#pragma mark - Timer Function

-(NSArray *)getTimeFromSring:(NSString *)time
{

    //only accepting time format hh:mm:ss

    NSMutableArray *resultArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    int count=1;
    for(int i=0;i<[time length];i++)
    {

        unichar ch = [time characterAtIndex: i];
        if(ch!=':' && count<=3)
        {
             NSString *appendString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",ch];
            [resultArr addObject:appendString];
        }
        else
        {
            count++;
        }

    }
    return resultArr;
}
```

## Finally

```
-(void)start:(NSTimer *)timer
{
  if(_timer==nil)
  {
    startDate =[NSDate date];

    _timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(timer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
  }

  if(_timer!=nil)
  { 
    float pauseTime = -1*[pauseStart timeIntervalSinceNow];

    [_timer setFireDate:[previousFireDate initWithTimeInterval:pauseTime sinceDate:previousFireDate]];
  }

}

-(void)timer:(NSTimer *)timer
{
  NSInteger secondsSinceStart = (NSInteger)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];

  NSInteger seconds = secondsSinceStart % 60;
  NSInteger minutes = (secondsSinceStart / 60) % 60;
  NSInteger hours = secondsSinceStart / (60 * 60);
  NSString *result = nil;
  if (hours > 0) 
  {
    result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
  }
  else 
  {
    result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds];        
  }

  label.text=result;

  NSLog(@"time interval -> %@",result);
}

-(void)stop
{
  if(_timer!=nil)
  {
    endDate = [NSDate date];
 NSLog(@"endate%@",endDate);

     NSTimeInterval interval = [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
NSLog(@"total time %f",interval);
    [_timer invalidate];
    _timer = nil; 
  startDate=nil;
  }
}
```

Comment: [NSTimer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possible approaches, depending on the specifics of what you want to do:

1. Keep track of the elapsed time and subtract it from the start time.
2. Calculate the end time at the start and figure out the difference between the current time and then.

Comment: -how i will track time from NSString.. i didn't get you.i am unable to set timer from nsstring.. i have deduct 1second after timer tick.

Comment: @steveAppleiOS: Ideally, you don't track time from a string. You track time and make an NSString from the time, not vice-versa.

Comment: i have a predifined time in uilabel, so i have to decrement time from it

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these examples, maybe they will help you:)

https://github.com/mineschan/MZTimerLabel

https://github.com/TriggerTrap/TTCounterLabel